# Repeating formula over a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test3()

    Range("C23").Formula = "=SUM(C16:C22)"
    Range("D23").Formula = "=SUM(D16:D22)"
    Range("E23").Formula = "=SUM(E16:E22)"
    Range("F23").Formula = "=SUM(F16:F22)"
    Range("G23").Formula = "=SUM(G16:G22)"
    Range("H23").Formula = "=SUM(H16:H22)"
    Range("I23").Formula = "=SUM(I16:I22)"
    
    Range("K16").Formula = "=J16-C23"
    Range("K17").Formula = "=J17-D23"
    Range("K18").Formula = "=J18-E23"
    Range("K19").Formula = "=J19-F23"
    Range("K20").Formula = "=J20-G23"
    Range("K21").Formula = "=J21-H23"
    Range("K22").Formula = "=J22-I23"

End Sub
```

How do I simplify this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether your code can be simplified, then yes.  For the first group, you can use this instead...

```
Range("C23:I23").Formula = "=SUM(C16:C22)"
```

For the second one, you can use this...

```
Range("K16:K22").Formula = "=SUM(J16-INDEX($C$23:$I$23, ROWS(K$16:K16)))"
```